# How to apply Leave-one-Group-out cross validation in sklearn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, scikit-learn

I am building a Naive Bayes classifier (nb) using sklearn.

The dataset consists of 4 subjects with each a different amount of labeled data.

I want to apply leave-one-subject-out cross validation, but I do not find a comparable example on the internet.

My data consists of the following:

```
x = [[2,0],[3,1],[2,1],[3,2]], [[4,2],[5,3],[5,2],[5,3]], [[7,3],[6,2],[7,1],[6,2]], [[2,3],[2,4],[3,4],[2,3]]]
y = [[0,1,3,2],[1,2,3,2],[0,1,1,1],[0,1,2,1]]
```

So the data of each subject is a subarray in x with the corresponding subarray of y. The input features consists of 2 elements each (for example the mean and std of an accelerometer).

I found on the internet the example of

> sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneOut

But this does not work in my example since I want to take data of a whole subject as a test set.

Is there a good equivalent for my needs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sklearn's method `LeaveOneGroupOut` is what you're looking for, just pass a `group` parameter that will define each subject to leave out from the train set. From the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#leave-one-group-out):

> Each training set is thus constituted by all the samples except the ones related to a specific group.

to adapt it to your data, just concatenate the list of lists.

```
import itertools
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneGroupOut

joined_x = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x))
joined_y = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(y))

logo = LeaveOneGroupOut()
for train, test in logo.split(joined_x, joined_y, groups=joined_y):
    print("%s %s" % (train, test))
>>>
[ 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  9 10 11 13 14 15] [ 0  8 12]
[ 0  2  3  5  6  7  8 12 14] [ 1  4  9 10 11 13 15]
[ 0  1  2  4  6  8  9 10 11 12 13 15] [ 3  5  7 14]
[ 0  1  3  4  5  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15] [2 6]
```

In the first training set group 0 is the test, the second group 1 and so on.

### EDIT

As @JanDM requested, to use it with `cross_val_score` the `groups` parameter should be passed as it is [pass to](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13af77c76e150b753485c662b7c52a41a2/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L255) the `split()` method of the crossvalidator `cv`

```
import itertools
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
cross_val_score(estimator, joined_x, joined_y, cv=logo, groups=joined_y)
```

Comment: Could you update your answer on how to use this in combination with the sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score()? I don't see how it would work together

Comment: @JanD.M. please see the edit, just need to pass a `groups` parameter to `cross_val_score`

Comment: So this means the Groups are my labels y? I am not sure